# Does it make sense to call insertObject after insertNewObjectForEntityForName?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm looking at some legacy code which I'm suspicious is causing an issue (sometimes later in the execution I'm getting >1 fetchResults with the same identifier):

```
if(createIfAbsent && ([fetchResults count] == 0)) {
       KHNode *node = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"KHNode" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
       node.identifier = aKey; 
       [self.managedObjectContext insertObject:node];
       fetchResults = [NSArray arrayWithObject:node];
}
```

Predicate I'm using is:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(identifier = %@)", aKey];
```

Does the insertObject call make any sense or is that just replicating insertNewObjectForEntityForName? Does it have any effect or side-effects? Could it be adding the same object twice?